# Setting data to the elem using jquery.tmpl

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-templates

I have set the data to div element and append it to another div element like this,

```
var dt = { id: 0 };
$.template("temp", '<div id="div2" >${id}</div>');
$.tmpl("temp", dt).appendTo("#div1");
```

Its working fine. I am appending it in document ready method.

My requirement is, Its(div2) click event i have to access dt.

Is it possible?

Question 2: i have set this data to a lot of elements. How to get those elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to access the variable dt? Or is this just one example and you will have many variables like dt?

Comment: yes, its just one example. i have updated my question much deeper. Could you look on it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.tmplItem](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmplitem/):

```
var dt = { id: 222, text: 'My value id 222' };

$.template("temp", '<div class="innerDiv" >${id}</div>');
$.tmpl("temp", dt).appendTo("#div1");

$(document).on('click', '.innerDiv', function() {
    // gets the data item associated to the rendered template
    var dataItem = $.tmplItem(this);
    // dataItem.data holds the data itself
    alert(dataItem.data.text);
});
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/wzy7M/)**

---

For the second question, I don't know a way to easily get the list of renderings of a specific template with the API.

What you could do though is to add a `data-` attribute to your template markup which would allow you to retrieve them easily:

```
$.template("temp", '<div id="div2" data-tmpl="temp">${id}</div>');
```

Then you can select all renderings which has an attribute "data-tmpl" with value "temp":

```
$('[data-tmpl="temp"]')
```

I have updated the demo in that way.

Maybe there is some other way but I'm that familiar with jQuery template.

Comment: Thanks, could you answer for 2nd question?